# Altair: not sorting an axis

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

Here is some simple sample code demonstrating the problem I would like to solve:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

categoryNames    = [ 'a', 'f', 'r', 'u', 'p' ]
categories       = pd.Series( categoryNames )
categories.index = categoryNames

amountsRaw       = [ 50, -100, 75, 100, -500 ]
amounts          = pd.Series( amountsRaw )
amounts.index    = categoryNames

df = pd.DataFrame( { "Amounts" : amounts, "Categories" : categories } )

alt.Chart( df ).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Categories',
    y='Amounts',
    color = alt.condition( alt.datum.Amounts > 0, alt.value( 'green' ), alt.value( 'red' ) )
)
```

This will produce a bar chart, but I do not want the x-axis categories sorted. They need to appear in the same order as they do in the categoryNames array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a list to the `sort` property of the `alt.X` encoding to control the order of the categories. For example:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Categories', sort=categoryNames),
    y='Amounts',
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.Amounts > 0, alt.value('green'), alt.value('red'))
)
```

[image]

Comment: This actually works great, except for when I try to use it in the "Simple Bar Chart with Labels" example, then the axis goes back to being sorted. https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_labels.html

Comment: That's a known bug in Vega-Lite: see https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2177 and https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/820

Comment: Ah great catch. And seems a solution is slowly in the works.  Thanks!